# Session not been set

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function action_adicionar_item()
{
    $lista_item_pedido = array();
    $x = 0;
    if(Session::has('lista_item_pedido'))
    {
        foreach(Session::get('lista_item_pedido') as $item)
        {
            $lista_item_pedido[$x] = $item;
            $x++;
        }
    }

    $lista_item_pedido[$x] = Input::all();

    Session::put('lista_item_pedido', $lista_item_pedido);
}
```

The first time I ran this method, the session is not created so the if is ignored and it sets the array value and should define the session with name a value but it doesn't.

The second time I call it, the session is created but with no values, what is weird.

Any ideas why on my first run the session is created with the empty array?

`Input::all()` is returning the correct values.

I have checked the file `storage/sessions/` the file is created and the value is set correctly:

```
s:17:"lista_item_pedido";a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:3:"162";s:10:"referencia";s:12:"112233445566";s:9:"descricao";s:6:"Sapato";s:5:"grade";s:14:"Grade 41 ao 46";s:8:"grade_id";s:1:"4";s:5:"valor";s:5:"50.00";s:10:"fornecedor";s:2:"30";}}}s:13:"last_activity";i:1340395110;}
```

This is created the first time I run the method, so it is created but I can't access it, only when I add two values and in this case, the first is ignored.

Comment: Let us see `Session::put` code.

Comment: Which framework? Impossible to answer if we can't see the code.

Comment: There is a tag, I'm using Laravel...it works fine, the weird is that it works only the second time I execute the method, when it doesn't go inside the IF it doesn't work

Comment: I'm using `Session::put` several times on my code. I think this time I have a logic problem

Comment: Which session driver are you using? (memory? memcached? file? database?)

Comment: I've browsed Laravel's code... `Session::put` simply updates the session array. This data is saved by `Session::save`, which is "called automatically at the end of the request". **Maybe** it is not being called as it should... I'd add a `Session::save();` line after the "put" line, only to test and check it this is the case (if it is, next we should discover why `Session::save` was not called...)

Comment: Ok..thanks for the time, gonna try that

Comment: Nothing =/ Updated the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12925/discussion-between-j-bruni-and-daniel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) instead...